# Como Linkar a boost library no codeblocks! (linux fedora)

Tags: c++, linux, codeblocks

Olá, Eu baixei a o arquivo boost.tar, extrai, compilei e instalei ele no meu fedora 23!
Mas não consigo fazer o codeblocks linkar essas novas bibliotcas.

Como faço para linkar?

Comment: em fedora seria de esperar que usasses apenas `sudo dnf install codeblocks`

Answer (score 0):

ok, consegui fazer o uso da biblioteca boost

Consegui os pacotes nesses links
https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=boost-devel
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html

No code blocks vc cria seu projeto vai no menu project>>build Options

Na aba searh directories >>compiler>>add e adiciona o caminhoa usr/include/boost

Na aba linker settings vai em add e procura a biblioteca que você deseja incluir! elas se encontram em usr/lib64 (no meu caso esta na lib64 mas pode estar na pasta lib)